# Кодек utf-8 не может декодировать байт 0xd0 в позиции 0

Tags: python, utf-8, конвертация, байты

Проблема такова - учусь питону, создал код себе для наглядности, а
там через раз выскакивает ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maminhacker/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/txt.py", line 4, in <module>
    a = input('Операция?(r - прочитать, w - создать, пересоздать, a - добавить в файл):')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Типо 1 раз работает, 1 раз выскакивает ошибка и опять 1 раз работает, и снова. Я уже перепробовал все, что знал. Например попробовал в конце кода `a = input('Операция?(r - прочитать, w - создать, пересоздать, a - добавить в файл):')` написать через запятую `encoding = 'utf=8'` и попробовать то же самое во всем остальном коде. Не знаю правильно я пытался исправить ошибку, но я что-то попытался сделать. Я даже, наверное, уже знаю что надо делать, но не знаю как.
частичка кода:

```
a = input('Операция?(r - прочитать, w - создать, пересоздать, a - добавить в файл):')
    
    text = input( 'Файл с которым будем работать:' )
        if a == 'r':
            file = open(text, 'r', encoding='utf-8') # на всякий случай переконвертировал в utf-8
        print('В этом файле написано:')
        print(file.read())
        file.close()
```

Надеюсь поможете, потому что на этом сайте точного ответа я так и не нашел.

Comment: У Вас исходный файл в другой кодировке, вот о чём ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но в какой тогда должен быть файл и код? Если надо убрать "encoding='utf-8'", то у меня и без него та же самая ошибка появляется. Простите если я слишком тупой)

Comment: для начала надо выяснить, в какой всё же у Вас кодировке файл. Например, в Windows это по умолчанию cp1251 в случае с русской версией ОС. Открывается он с параметром encoding='cp1251', и если у Вас например python3 - вы сразу же получаете всё в utf-8.

Comment: Я сейчас на Ubuntu, так что думаю у меня python3 (он так и называется в терминале)

Comment: тогда попробуйте определить кодировку в консоли вот так: file  путь_и_имя_файла.

Comment: В файле кодировка utf-8, ещё я перевёл ошибку и там оказывается вообще сказано другое "Кодек utf-8 не может декодировать байт 0xd0 в позиции 0: недопустимый байт продолжения"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто хотел мне помочь, я в итоге решил проблему. Я не совсем уверен, что я именно сделал, но я, после запуска кода, удивился, что там не высвечиваются и не копируются некоторые сообщения, проверив код, я увидел, что я не дописал кое-где его (ну, чтобы код мог прочитать файл, перезаписать и т.д.), после этого проблема решилась. Я опять же не уверен, что дело было в этом, возможно я убрал ошибку во время этого исправления и добавления недостающего кода, и просто не заметил.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).